# Including Javascript and CSS in WordPress theme options

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working on delving into more complex WordPress theme options pages. Right now, I need to do a couple things:

1. Create a tabbed interface for the theme options page to tab between different types of options
2. Create a jQuery-driven header image selector. The default header selector (i.e. the one included in twentyten) is insufficient.

So, what I need to work out how to do is include JS and CSS in the theme options page.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-better-wordpress-options-panel/

Comment: Absolutely perfect, spent some time Googling but it was one of the harder things to dig up. Shoulda known NetTuts would have covered it.

Thanks!